# How to rewrite a stream of HTML tokens into a new document?

Tags: html, parsing, tokenize

Suppose I have an HTML document that I have tokenized, how could I transform it into a new document or apply some other transformations?

For example, suppose I have this HTML:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p><a href="/foo">text</a></p>
  <p>Hello <span class="green">world</span></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I have currently written is a tokenizer that outputs a stream of tokens. For this document they would be (written in pseudo code):

```
TAG_OPEN[html] TAG_OPEN[body] TAG_OPEN[p] TAG_OPEN[a] TAG_ATTRIBUTE[href]
TAG_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE[/foo] TEXT[text] TAG_CLOSE[a] TAG_CLOSE[p]
TAG_OPEN[p] TEXT[Hello] TAG_OPEN[span] TAG_ATTRIBUTE[class]
TAG_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE[green] TEXT[world] TAG_CLOSE[span] TAG_CLOSE[p]
TAG_CLOSE[body] TAG_CLOSE[html]
```

But now I don't have any idea how could I use this stream to create some transformations.

For example, I would like to rewrite `TAG_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE[/foo]` in `TAG_OPEN[a] TAG_ATTRIBUTE[href]` to something else.

Another transformation I would like to do is make it output `TAG_ATTRIBUTE[href]` attributes after the `TAG_OPEN[a]` in parenthesis, for example,

```
<a href="/foo">text</a>
```

gets rewritten into

```
<a href="/foo">text</a>(/foo)
```

What is the general strategy for doing such transformations? There are many other transformations I would like to do, like stripping all tags and just leaving TEXT content, adding tags after some specific tags, etc.

Do I need to create the parse tree? I have never done it and don't know how to create a parse tree from a stream of tokens. Or can I do it somehow else?

Any suggestions are welcome.

And one more thing - I would like to learn all this parsing myself, so I am not looking for a library!

Thanks beforehand, Boda Cydo

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that the html is xml compliant, then xslt would be a way to go.  But I am assuming that would be out as you seem to want to write your own parser (not sure why).
If you really want to write a parser (I'd write parse rules, not your own parser engine) take a look at antlr and MS oslo.

Comment: More power to you.  Just think you're going about it the wrong way - using the wrong tool/paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of parsing/traversing an XML/HTML tree. Perhaps I can point you to:-

http://razorsharpcode.blogspot.com/2009/10/combined-pre-order-and-post-order-non.html

If you want to do pre-order or post-order manipulation of DOM elements, you can use the algorithm described there.